# Braced initialisation of std::any

Tags: c++, c++17

When declaring std::any object of a class type the below three ways of initialising the object works properly.

```
class B{

};

std::any a;
a.emplace<B>();

std::any b = std::make_any<B>();

std::any c(B());
```

But when used with braced initialisation like

```
std::any d{B()};
```

The class's destructor gets called twice resulting in undefined behaviour.

Is this behaviour something by design?

Comment: `c` is not an object. And the "undefined behavior" of `d` is only a sign of a poorly written class `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  std::any d{B()};
}
```

two instances of `B` are created in the above block, and two are destroyed.  One temporary `B()` and one within the `any`.

Odds are you violated the rule of 0/3/5, and do not have a correct copy/move ctor.

```
std::any c(B());
```

`c` is a function, not a variable.  That is vexing, but it is a legacy rule for compatibility with [c](/questions/tagged/c); if a declaration can be parsed as a function, it will be.

```
{
  std::any a;
  a.emplace<B>();
}
```

no temporary is created here.  One `B` is created within the `any` and destroyed.

```
{
  std::any b = std::make_any<B>();
}
```

ditto.

You have a bug in your unshared `B` class, it doesn't handle being moved and then both copies destroyed.

Comment: I overlooked the function vs object creation for c, thanks for pointing it out. For object d, is the temporary object mandatory, can't the compiler work it out based on how it is being initialised and do away with temporary object?

Comment: @dinesh The compiler can eliminate it under the "asn0 if" rule, but your code with the bug means it cannot.  And it may not.  Code that generates a bug there is going to cause bugs elsewhere, so fix the bug.